# When to use "If I was" vs. "If I were"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, conditionals, subjunctive-mood, irrealis-were

1. If I was...
2. If I were...

When is it correct to use "If I was" vs. "If I were" in standard English?

Comment: Closely related: [**If I was** an airline pilot vs. **If I had been** an airline pilot 10 years ago](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115736/if-i-was-an-airline-pilot-vs-if-i-had-been-an-airline-pilot-10-years-ago)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72674/discussion-on-question-by-avd-when-to-use-if-i-was-vs-if-i-were).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**SYNOPSIS**: Sometimes it **must** be *“if I was”*, but at other times it **can** be *“if I were”* —  and for some speakers in those cases, perhaps even **must** be *“if I were”* in their idiolect.

---

Sentences with the subordinating conjunction *if* normally contain two
clauses, each with its own subject and verb. The question asks what to do
about the past-tense *be* verb in the “if” clause.

Unfortunately, as it’s currently worded the question can have no answer that is
simultaneously all of **short, complete, *and* correct**.  That’s because it doesn’t
provide enough context to know which one of many possible cases actually
applies here. I must therefore cover them all.

---

## Classification schemes

David Maule in his 1988 EFL paper titled [***‘Sorry, if he comes, I go’: teaching
conditionals***](http://eltj.oxfordjournals.org/content/42/2/117.abstract)
suggested that English conditionals be broadly classified as one of four
types depending on whether their outcomes were real vs. unreal and
past vs. non-past.  (Maule classifies these
based on their “then” part not on their “if” part, and as we shall see,
this is a useful way to organize them.)

- Class A: real non-past
- Class B: real past
- Class C: unreal non-past
- Class D: unreal past

Maule discovered that most English conditionals do not fit into the
narrow models typically presented to EFL students learning English.

Christian Jones and Daniel Waller built on Maule’s work with their own EFL paper in 2010,
[***If only it were true: the problem with the four
conditionals***](http://clok.uclan.ac.uk/1531/1/elt.ccp101.full_1531.pdf).
The authors sampled a random assortment of conditionals from the British
National Corpus and classified each as being one of Maule’s four categories
listed above.  They discovered that the real cases contained patterns in
both the past and the non-past that appeared very frequently in real
English, but which are rarely taught to learners.

### The Reals

The class B “real past” cases fit into three patterns:

1. If + present simple, past continuous
2. If + present simple, past simple
3. If + past simple, past simple

Of those three, the final pattern of having past simple in both
clauses was by far the most common of the three.  The sample
provided for that case was:

> ... if you **wanted**<sup>[real]</sup> to know the answer ... you **had**<sup>[real]</sup> to keep zapping from channel to channel.

Converting that into the first person singular to align with the asker’s question gives us:

> If I **wanted**<sup>[real]</sup> to know the answer, I **had**<sup>[real]</sup> to keep zapping from channel to channel.

And it just one step more to swap out *want* for *be*:

> **If I was**<sup>[real]</sup> interested in knowing the answer, **I had**<sup>[real]</sup> to keep zapping from channel to channel.

So here we discover the first of what shall prove to be several answers to
the asker’s question:

#### You use *If I was* in the “if” part when the “then” part is in the simple past.

These are always conditionals from Maule’s
class B. It would not be grammatical to use “If I were” there.

These “real past” cases happen all the time in real speech and real
writing, as Jones and Waller prove.

Consider this arrangement:

> If she **was**<sup>[real]</sup> already home when he got there, then she **took**<sup>[real]</sup> the bus.

That’s a real past case on both sides, and it would be ungrammatical to use
“If she were” to attempt to mean the same thing. You can also use a modal perfect in the consequent along with that past simple in the “if” part:

> If she **was**<sup>[real]</sup> already home when he got there, then she **must have taken** the bus.
>
> If she **was**<sup>[real]</sup> already home when he got there, then she **will have taken** the bus.

Those are all real cases, and you know by the “then” part.

### The Unreals

For Class C, the unreal non-pasts, there are many example patterns
provided, but the most common case by far uses “if” with past simple or
with a modal, then some modal in the consequent.

One provided example there is:

> ... I**’d give** it a good hiding if it **didn’t behave**.

However, there are many other Class C patterns, such as:

> ... if we **could get** three or four items, that **would be** very nice.
>
> ... if two members of staff **happen** to fall in love and **decide** to marry it **would be** churlish to be appointing blame.

The thing about using the past simple in something like “If it didn’t” is
that without looking further along in the sentence, this alone is not
enough to reveal whether it’s a Class B type that will take a real
consequent or whether it’s a Class C type that will take an unreal one.

### “If only it were true”, “I wish it were true”

Because we use the simple past tense in English for real and unreal conditionals, you normally cannot know whether it’s the unreal case until you hit the “then” portion. But in one unique yet common case, you can, and that is when a singular subject is governing the verb *be* in the past. That’s because the unreal case uses *were* no matter whether singular or plural.

So we could say:

> If a staff member **were** to fall in love, it **would be** churlish to assign blame.

That’s a Class C conditional because the “then” part has a *would be* in it. But you already knew it was going to be a hypothetical case when you saw the *“If a staff member **were”*** in the first half.

Recasting that into the first person singular provides the **second answer**
to the asker’s question:

> If I **were** to fall in love, it **would be** churlish to blame me for it.

This special, [modally marked](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/145174/2085) form of *be* is used only for an unreal
hypothetical. It is a relic of the Old English past subjunctive, and it was once used for far more than we use it today.

Here alone can you detect through the morphology of the verb
that it is anything other than the past simple.  This is a Class C
conditional because it has an unreal non-past in its consequent: *“would be
churlish”*

**You cannot go wrong by using *were* for hypotheticals** like this, as it has
been the preferred use for centuries, particularly but not exclusively in America. Many careful writers still choose to
observe this distinction: you need but read some recent issue of *The Economist* magazine from the UK to find plenty of examples of this. Indeed,
English teachers at American schools have been known to mark various hypothetical uses of *was* as “wrong”, saying that it “should” be *were*.

#### Optional *were* in Class C conditionals

However, you should not flinch if — nay, **when** — you hear someone say
*“If I was... I would...”* as a Class C conditional in casual speech. This sometimes happens even in educated
speakers and writers, so you should not make anything of it. Some writers prefer not to do that, but unless the person complaining is your English teacher, you shouldn’t let it get to you. (Yes, this is ungrammatical for some people. For others, it is not.)

It could be that those writers or speakers using *“If I was...would”* in their conditionals have
chosen not to convey the nuance, or perhaps did not consider
such a distinction meaningful in their own speech. Some are even
unaware that the distinction exists.

Because of the redundancy in language where the *would* in the “then” part gives it away, it’s not really needed anyway; everyone will still know what you mean.

These forms are still unreal cases even when they aren’t modally marked as unreal, singular *were*. Because in all cases except for this unique case of *was/were* you cannot ever morphologically distinguish a real case from an unreal one in English, you have to decide whether it’s unreal by looking at the “then” part, not the “if” part (at least, not reliably).

That means you need to train yourself to tell the real case:

> If she **was**<sup>[real]</sup> already home when he got there, then she **took**<sup>[real]</sup> the bus.

From the unreal case:

> If she **were**<sup>[unreal]</sup> already home when he got there, he **wouldn’t have**<sup>[unreal]</sup> to run pick her up himself.

Even when the unreal case uses the past simple not unreal past in the “if” part the way some speakers do:

> If she **was**<sup>[“unreal”]</sup> already home when he got there, he **wouldn’t have**<sup>[unreal]</sup> to run pick her up himself.

That last example above is real in form but it is still unreal in sense because of the *would*. Some writers disapprove of that style of using *was* for a hypothetical, but it’s not uncommon, especially in speech.

Moreover, you **cannot somehow make it be “less hypothetical”** merely by using *“was...would”*; that’s just as hypothetical as *“were...would”* for the reasons already stated.

One final common construction uses past perfect in the “if” part and a modal perfect in the “then” part:

> If she **had been**<sup>[unreal]</sup> already home when he got there, he **wouldn’t have had**<sup>[unreal]</sup> to run pick her up himself.

Although that’s a common way to set up a unreal case with perfects on both sides, there are many other ways, including using a non-perfect unreal past in the “if”:

> If she **were**<sup>[unreal]</sup> already home when he got there, he **wouldn’t have had**<sup>[unreal]</sup> to run pick her up himself.

Yes, it’s somehow “unbalanced” with respect to the perfect aspect, but English doesn’t have an obligatory sequence-of-tenses rule like some languages do, and we often use a simple past instead of a perfect one because it’s...simpler that way.

## Inverted Conditionals without *if*

There is one relatively uncommon place where you pretty much do have to use *were* not *was* in a conditional, and that is when you use **inversion** to forgo the word *if* altogether:

> **Were**<sup>[unreal]</sup> there any other way, we **would have**<sup>[unreal]</sup> found it.

That’s the same as saying:

> If there **were**<sup>[unreal]</sup> any other way, we **would have**<sup>[unreal]</sup> found it.

or even as saying:

> If there **had been**<sup>[unreal]</sup> any other way, we **would have**<sup>[unreal]</sup> found it.

But that last one lends itself to an inverted version:

> **Had there been**<sup>[unreal]</sup> any other way, we **would have**<sup>[unreal]</sup> found it.

The subject–verb inversion is something of a stealth conditional because it doesn’t use the word *if*. The inversion alone is enough to signal that it’s what used to be called a “subjunctive” use (back when English had an actual subjunctive). It doesn’t **have** to use *be*, but if you do use *be* for it, you should certainly use *were*. Other verbs in the past tense work the same, with the inversion signalling the conditional:

> **Had<sup>[unreal]</sup> they** but asked, we **would have**<sup>[unreal]</sup> gladly told them.

You’ll find this “subjunctive inversion” style in formal writing, but very rarely if ever in extemporaneous, casual speaking. That’s because inversion isn’t all that normal, so it’s a marked form. Consider how stiffly formal this Steven Brust quote mentioned in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/180182/2085) sounds:

> To be more precise, and state the matter in its simplest form, we believe that **were<sup>[unreal]</sup> any** of the events in the previous volume of such a nature that they could be omitted without severe damage to the narrative, we **should have omitted**<sup>[unreal]</sup> them to begin with.
>
> ― [*The Lord of Castle Black*, by Steven Brust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Viscount_of_Adrilankha)

There instead of writing out the conditional the long way with *“if any were”*, to be more formal Brust wrote it with inversion: *“were any”*. (He’s **also** playing on the modal duality of *should*, but that’s something else again.)

If you ever get the chance to read English literature from a couple centuries ago or better, you might even come upon conditional inversion used with the bare infinitive in what has historically been called a “present subjunctive” use:

> **Be ye**<sup>[unreal]</sup> man or mouse, still **shall ye** say nothing!

That’s using inversion to skip the *if*, as though it were:

> **If ye be**<sup>[unreal]</sup> man or mouse, still **shall ye** say nothing!

Nobody talks that way anymore, and nobody writes that way anymore, either, not unless they intend to represent the speech of centuries long past. Instead we’d just say:

> No matter whether you **are** a man or a mouse, you still **will say** nothing!

---

### Further Reading

I have related answers here:

- [subjunctive in a “non-if” hypothetical clause](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/339053/2085)
- [“Be them” or “be they”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/90347/2085)
- [If I were him, I would doubt if she (is/was/were?) serious about this relationship](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/145174/2085)
- [How is the English Subjunctive Composed?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/156416/2085)
- [Present subjunctive with synonyms of lest](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/420862/2085)

Comment: re *"to be deliberately archaizing Brust wrote..."*   When I write a formal letter (e-mail, these days) I often use inversions  such as "had there been" "should you have" or "were you to" to convey a formal tone but I had no idea I would be archaizing.

Comment: @Centaurus You’re right, so I’ve re­moved that bit. Mere “sub­junc­tive in­ver­sion” 
for con­di­tion­als by it­self is **not** ar­chaiz­ing, al­though it is
more of­ten to be found in writ­ing than in speech and so might be
“for­mal­iz­ing”. Brust is writ­ing a char­ac­ter there who’s 
pur­pose­fully stuffy. (*continued*...)

Comment: @Centaurus (*continued*) His word-play on *we should* is pos­si­ble 
be­cause most peo­ple would today say *we would* but Brust is us­ing
the “old” “1st-per­son” fla­vor of *we should* where in
mod­ern times we’d be much more likely to say *we would*. He did so be­cause this way he
al­lows for both modal­i­ties of *should* — the epis­temic sense of 
prob­a­bil­ity and the de­on­tic sense of obli­ga­tion — to si­mul­ta­ne­ously
en­ter into the read­er’s mind for the delectably sub­tle, hu­mor­ous ef­fect.

Comment: There's at least one inversion which can only really be thought of as indicative in modern 21st century English, the one with *should* - as in *Should you see Centaurus, ask him to ping me*.

Comment: I'd say "Whether man or mouse, still you'll say nothing!" Or even "Man or mouse, still you'll say nothing." Good answer, though. I hadn't seen it before. Well worthy of canonical status.

Comment: I suspect that even many of those who those who prefer irrealis (and counterfactual) 'If I were you, I'd ...' would use 'I suspect the police here would do the same if the situation wasn't under control'.

Answer (score 91):

When in doubt, always use the **subjunctive** mood:

> If I were you...

It will make you sound **smarter** and it is **technically correct** since "the subjunctive mood is used to express a wish or possible situation that is currently not true."

Comment: Please provide references to support this answer. The year is now 2018 and smartypants answers are not exactly commendable :)

Comment: Previous comments have been moved to chat, but since this answer remains accepted (and the asker apparently AWOL), this should be stated here: **THIS ANSWER IS NOT CORRECT**. The subjunctive mood is NOT always the right option. See Nick’s answer for a much better explanation.

Comment: **MODERATOR NOTE:** Aw gee, can't you guys **ᴘʀᴇᴛᴛʏ ᴘʟᴇᴀsᴇ *ᴡɪᴛʜ sᴜɢᴀʀ ᴏɴ ɪᴛ*** carry on your discussion either in this [**answer’s chatroom**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72677/discussion-on-answer-by-edward-tanguay-when-to-use-if-i-was-vs-if-i-were), or in this [**question’s chatroom**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72674/discussion-on-question-by-avd-when-to-use-if-i-was-vs-if-i-were), or even in the [**main ELU chatroom**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/di-kmprhnsb-rum) where people actually hang out? I've manually copied your comments into this answer’s chatroom.

Comment: This answer appears to be a bit of satire that was so successful that it got taken for a real piece of advice, and irritated some people. Repeatedly. Rather like Macchiavelli.

Comment: Meta discussion: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12089/undeleted-deleting-a-highly-upvoted-but-questionably-correct-answer-the-one-wi?cb=1

Comment: This bald statement would be helped immensely by minimal statistics over like [the relevant (but questionable) history in NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=If+I+was%2C+If+I+were&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). But a plain google search comparison shows that "If I was you" is perfectly acceptable _nowadays_.

Comment: @Mitch It always has been.

Answer (score 78):

It's *if I were* for hypothetical in the present or future and *if I was* when talking about something presumed true in the PAST.  "IF" then means something likened to "since".

> If I were class president, I would represent our class very well for the next four years.
>
> If I was at the party last night, I don't remember.

It's an old, residual rule from the days of yore when English verbs conjugated differently for person and singular/plural in both the *past* and *present tense indicative* and *subjunctive*.  While I may not have enough knowledge on Old and Middle English, I can show you the conjugation for *to do* for the 2nd person singular form of "thou" in Early Modern English:

> present indicative - thou *dost*
> present subjunctive - thou *do*
> past indicative - thou *didst*
> past subjunctive - thou *did*

It's why it should be "if I be" for things possible and one could still say it.  We see "if truth be told" and "whether it be" and others, all residual subjunctives from the days of Chaucer and even Shakespeare wherein it was already disappearing.  In Modern English, the past tense is uniform for every person (*I, you, he, we, you, they did*) except for "to be" (*I, he was, but you, we, you, they were*), but it wasn't always that way.

Anyway, if I were you, I would learn it because it usually separates the intelligent from ignoramuses.  It's correct English even if it be a little old.

Answer (score 32):

Well, "if I was" *can* be valid for the past, I guess.

> If I was wrong, please forgive me.

That aside, I think one of the other answers is right that in British English — at least spoken — both are acceptable and probably equally common. (The 'were' version sounds more 'educated'.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72675/discussion-on-answer-by-benjol-when-to-use-if-i-was-vs-if-i-were).

Answer (score 16):

> The rule that I was taught is that *was*
>   is for things that could be true but
>   aren't, and *were* is for things that
>   could never be true.
>
> So, *if I was an airline pilot* is OK
>   because conceivably I could retrain as
>   a pilot, if I wanted.
>
> But *if I were you* is right because I
>   will never be you.

The rule you were taught is wrong, Daniel.

The few subjunctive forms that are left can all be stated in other fashions using language that isn't subjunctive in form. We use lexical verbs to state subjunctive/contrary to fact situations all the time.

If I lived in Bangkok, ... // If I had a million dollars, ... // If I hadn't been born, ... .

Just as we can use the past time FORM of lexical verbs to describe contrary to fact situations, so too we can use 'was'. It's not as formal as the subjunctive form 'were' but it means the same thing.

There's not a speaker of English anywhere who thinks that "If I was you" means that the speaker is saying "I am you".

"If I were you" means the same thing as "If I was you". They both entail that I am not you.

Of course, we can and do use 'was' to state "allowing that that's true":

*If she was at the party, she sure was quiet.*

Comment: As you indicate, saying, "If I was you" would almost certainly not cause confusion (except perhaps some confusion about this rule), but it would make people think you didn't finish high school.

Answer (score 14):

Younger people would never use 'were', here in Australia at least. From the point of view of grammar, both are OK nowadays. It's interesting to note, that IELTS would accept both while TOEFL would be very reluctant to accept 'was'.

Comment: re "younger people would never use "were"".   Do they say "If I was you"?

Comment: @Centaurus Yes, in my region of Australia. You might also hear "I goes" and "Should have went".

Comment: In any country, there are well-educated young people and poorly-educated young people. In Australia the former do still use *were* in this context but in fewer numbers, and the latter were always less likely to use it, some from lack of exposure to the "correct" form, and others from an awareness of "proper English" combined with a class-proud refusal to "talk more genteel".

Answer (score 10):

The rule that I was taught is that *was* is for things that **could** be true but aren't, and *were* is for things that could never be true.

So, *if I was an airline pilot* is OK because conceivably I could retrain as a pilot, if I wanted.

But *if I were you* is right because I will never be you.

Comment: "If I was an airline pilot" and "If I were an airline pilot" have different meanings. The latter is the subjunctive case (and presumably what most people *mean*, even if they say the former). The former is talking about the past tense - "if I was an airline pilot 10 years ago..."

Comment: Before I had ever heard of Martha and had seen the caliber of her contributions, one of my first [questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115736/if-i-was-an-airline-pilot-vs-if-i-had-been-an-airline-pilot-10-years-ago) as a novice was inspired by the comment above.  She is very good, and she writes impeccably well. But here she is wrong.

Comment: Martha is right about the meaning of "if I was a pilot", so most people saying that would either be drunk, losing their memories big-time, or misusing the English language.

Answer (score 10):

The rule is, if your hypothetical scenario suggests something that isn't true, use were:

> If I were stronger, I'd break your arm!

(I'm not stronger.)

> If I were a flower, I'd go crazy!

(I'm not really a flower, though I've been called a pansy before.)

> If my room were clean, it would be a first.

(My room isn't clean.)

If it may be true, use was:

> If this answer was poorly constructed, it may have been due to the fact that I was really tired.

(It may be poorly written.)

The same rules apply to sentences with *though*:

> He appears as though he were homeless.

(He's not homeless, yet, although keeping up his current dressing habits could result in such.)

This is addressed, among other places, on pages 56-57 of my favorite reference book, "Woe Is I" by Patricia O' Conner.

Also see
http://m.grammarbook.com/grammar-rules/subject-and-verb-agreement.aspx from which I quote:

> Rule 10. The word *were* replaces *was* in sentences that express a wish or are contrary to fact:
>
> ***Example:** If Joe **were** here, you'd be sorry.*
>
> Shouldn't *Joe* be followed by *was*, not *were*, given that *Joe* is singular? But Joe isn't actually here, so we say *were*, not *was*. The sentence demonstrates the **subjunctive mood**, which is used to express things that are hypothetical, wishful, imaginary, or factually contradictory. The subjunctive mood pairs singular subjects with what we usually think of as plural verbs.
>
> ***Examples:**
> I wish it **were** Friday.
> She requested that he **raise** his hand.*
>
> In the first example, a wishful statement, not a fact, is being expressed; therefore, *were*, which we usually think of as a plural verb, is used with the singular subject I.
>
> Normally, *he raise* would sound terrible to us. However, in the second example, where a request is being expressed, the subjunctive mood is correct.
>
> Note: The subjunctive mood is losing ground in spoken English but should still be used in formal speech and writing.

Answer (score 6):

## Real Past

***If I was***: This phrase uses the past indicative mood, and it is used to state a fact that could be true. Have you ever gotten an e-mail from Twitter telling you about a suspicious login? They say, "If this *was* your login, don't worry about it," because that login to your account the other day could be yours, but Twitter isn't sure.

## Unreal Past

***If I were***: This phrase uses the past subjunctive mood, and it is used in situations in which the speaker is wishfully thinking. I want to be taller, so I sometimes I say, "If I were taller, my life would be easier," but the fact of the matter is I'm not taller than I already am. I'm wishfully thinking about a situation that isn't true.

## Present

***If I be***/***If I am***: These phrases can be used interchangeably when the sentence refers to a future situation that could happen. The archaic *If I be* uses the present subjunctive while *If I am* uses the present indicative. Here are a few examples.

1. If you be good tomorrow, Mommy will buy you a cookie. (*archaic*)
2. If I am great during my speech for school president, maybe I will be elected.
3. Whether my future be promising or not, I know it will work out in the end. (*archaic*)

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if+you+be%2Cif+i+be%2Cif+he+be%2Cif+she+be%2Cif+they+be&year_start=1800&year_end=2017&corpus=15&smoothing=50&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cif%20you%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20i%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20he%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20she%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20they%20be%3B%2Cc0) shows that using the present subjunctive in this case is **rather archaic**, but it is still far from being incorrect. Again, the two moods can be used interchangeably in these cases.

Answer (score 4):

I think both can be said to be standard uses nowadays. I have read that American English uses the subjunctive ("If I were you") more than British English. I never use "If I were you" but always the "was" formation. In the same way I would never say "If he be right", etc.

Comment: An American would not say _if he be right_ too.

Comment: @Shinto Sherlock: the past tense of the subjunctive moode is used to express an imaginary or hypothetical condition, as far as I know. I have never heard somebody saying _if I be rich, I would live in Hawaii_, or _if I am rich, I would be live in Hawaii._

Comment: Compare the previous sentence with "I request that Jill pick up the ball," which uses the present subjunctive to express a mandative statement. Subjunctive mood is used in the same way in both American and British English.

Comment: For this form of the subjunctive, [Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if+I+were+to%2Cif+I+was+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) doesn't show a marked American/British difference.

Comment: "If I was you" sounds hillbilly. I thought we had all the rednecks who were too busy herding cows to learn a lick of English.

Answer (score 3):

First things first.

When you're talking about a real situation, you should stick to either:

> (1) *If I **was**...*

[for the past time]

Or:

> (1') *If I **am**...*

[for the present or future time]

When you're talking about a hypothetical situation, you'll most likely be okay with:

> (2) *If I **were**...*

[for the present or future time]

The beauty of (2) is that it can be used even for the **past** time of a hypothetical situation. Yes, the original form for this would be:

> (3) *If I **had been**...*

But I've seen native speakers prefer to use (2) instead of (3) for the past time of a hypothetical situation, time and time again, especially in spoken English.

### So much for the basics...

There's a little but important twist in all this.

Although being correct, using (2) for a hypothetical situation in an informal context might make it sound a tad stronger than you want it to. I suppose this might be because ***were*** sounds stronger than ***was***.

Whatever the real reason may be, therefore, you might want to use (1) instead of (2) for a hypothetical situation in an informal context, unless of course you want to make it sound stronger for some contextual reason.

Sometimes, using (1) for a hypothetical situation might also make the speaker sound "cooler" as might be the case in this [clip of the movie 'KINGSMAN: THE GOLDEN CIRCLE'](https://youtu.be/Ay69jcyzrY4?t=40s), where Charlie says:

> *If I **was** you, I'd unlock your cab.*

Answer (score 1):

"If I was" is for a possible scenario, and "If I were" is for wild imaginations, unrealistic dreams, or, in general, hypothetical scenarios. The following examples should make it clear enough.

- If it was you, prove it.
- If I were you, I would not do that.