# Difference between 'If ..was' and 'If ...were'

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“If I was” or “If I were”. Which is more common, and which is correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/660/if-i-was-or-if-i-were-which-is-more-common-and-which-is-correct)

Hi,

I have seen different usage of the phrase 'If..was' and 'If..were'.  But I find it difficult to understand when to use which.

e.g. If I were the President of the United State, I would get the hell out of Iraq.

This looks correct. Can I use 'If I was' here?

Is there a rule?

Comment: See [“If I was” or “If I were”. Which is more common, and which is correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/660/), ['Was' vs 'Were' Word Usage in Stack Overflow Ad Image](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/), and [What happened to the subjunctive?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1209/).