# "If I were" or "If I was"?

Tags: tenses, subjunctive-mood

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [“If I was” or “If I were”. Which is more common, and which is correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/660/if-i-was-or-if-i-were-which-is-more-common-and-which-is-correct)
>   [“Was” versus “were”—word usage in Stack Overflow Ad Image](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/was-versus-wereword-usage-in-stack-overflow-ad-image)

Which one is correct:
"If I were a cop, I would wear a uniform"
OR
"If I was a cop, I would wear a uniform"?

Comment: General reference: ["What happened to the subjunctive?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1209/what-happened-to-the-subjunctive)

Comment: Possible duplicates: ["_If it was_ or _If it were_: Which is more common and which is correct"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/660/if-i-was-or-if-i-were-which-is-more-common-and-which-is-correct), and          ["Was" versus "were"  - word usage in Stack Overflow ad image](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/was-versus-wereword-usage-in-stack-overflow-ad-image)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**if I were**

This we call the *second conditional* utilising the subjunctive form, which can be used to discuss hypothetical/unreal situations.

*If I were a cop, I would wear a uniform* implies that I am not a cop and so I don't wear a uniform.

**if it was**

This would be the beginning of a question about a past event, for example:

*If it was raining, why did you go out?* meaning that it rained and you went outside; the speaker is questioning your motives.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

+1 Karl

But as to correctness, both are "correct".

There is also:

- Were I a cop, I would wear a uniform.

I think "were I" sounds very elegant, especially the passive "Were I to be". I'd like to find opportunity to use this in speech and get away with it without it sounding forced.