# "If I was"/"If I were": what's the right usage and why?

Tags: tenses, past-tense

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“If I was” or “If I were”. Which is more common, and which is correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/660/if-i-was-or-if-i-were-which-is-more-common-and-which-is-correct)

From what I have read so far both are correct and *was* is used in an informal way. But somehow statements like "If I was to lose my mind" sound incorrect.

Is the above sentence correct? Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

Read the answers on the other question for the full story.  But briefly: "If I was" is incorrect in your example, and in 99% of cases (there are a few examples, like "If I was wrong, I apologize", where it is not a subjunctive, so *was* is right).  Most people don't draw the distinction, so use *was* indiscriminately.

Answer (score -1):

"If I were" is generally used to describe imaginative situations which are considered highly-improbable or are not true, where as "If I was" is used for situations which are feasible yet uncertain.

For example:

"If I was wrong, I am sorry." -> A case about which the speaker is uncertain.

"If I were superman, I would fly above the clouds." -> A case which is impossible.