# Does "the attached updated User Guide" sound wrong?

Tags: grammaticality

I updated a User Guide, and according to my company's processes I have to send the document with tracked changes to our operations. So I wrote this email:

> Dear operations,
>
> Please take a look at the attached updated User Guide and let me know
>   blah blah.
>
> Blah,
>
> Blah Blah.

Does the sentence sound right or had I better rephrase it so as to avoid "attached updated"? For example,

> Please find the updated User Guide attached and let me know blah blah.

Comment: Although I support the accepted answer, I want to offer another alternative: *Please find the updated User Guide (attached) and let me know etc.*

Comment: @aparente001 Add a comma after the parenthesis, and you're good to go.

Comment: @SebastianPojman - A comma there would be optional.

Comment: @aparente001 Could you review my answer please? Thank you!

https://english.stackexchange.com/a/403340/231780

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both versions are grammatical.

*Please take a look at the attached updated User Guide and let me know...*

There is no rule which prohibits the use of two adjectives in a row before the noun they modify, as is the case with *updated* and *attached* here.

*Please find the updated User Guide attached and let me know...*

Here, *attached* is an elliptic form of a subordinate relative clause. The full form is:

*Please find the updated User Guide which is attached and let me know...*

Which one you will eventually choose depends on your stylistic preferences.

Comment: Make sure that you use *which* when it is an nonessential clause and *that* when it is an essential clause. Good answer anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The string of adjectives is fine, but I think you should either put a comma after *Guide* or start a new sentence after *Guide*. (Google: comma before conjunction in compound sentences).

*Please take a look at the attached updated User Guide, and let me know blah blah.*

or

*Please take a look at the attached updated User Guide. Let me know blah blah.*

You could also reword it:

*Please take a look at the updated User Guide, which is attached, and let me know blah blah.*

Or

*I have attached the updated User Guide. Please let me know blah blah.*

Answer (score 2):

Both work just fine because both have clauses with a subject and a verb, making them complete sentences, but as a native speaker of English, the second version sounds better to my ear.

Corrections to both need to be made, though.

1. Please take a look at the attached**,** updated **u**ser **g**uide**,** and let me know blah blah.
2. Please find the updated **u**ser **g**uide attached**,** and let me know blah blah.

I'm not sure what the details of your user guides are, but I'm guessing that those details (attached, updated) are not important, so I recommend putting a comma between them. You need a comma after "attached" and "guide" because it follows a clause starting with "and." You shouldn't capitalize "user guide" because it's not a proper noun (I'm only assuming this).

Answer (score 0):

Multiple adjectives in a row before a single noun is a notoriously tricky situation for non-native English speakers to master. It's perfectly grammatically correct and does not require any commas to separate them, but certain orders of adjectives sound very "wrong," while others sound fine. Unfortunately, it's difficult to come up with a comprehensive set of rules for the "correct"-sounding ordering, because it's based almost entirely on instinct and experience. See [here](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2016/sep/13/sentence-order-adjectives-rule-elements-of-eloquence-dictionary) for a discussion.

But in your specific case, the phrase "attached updated User Guide" sounds perfectly fine to me.