# Correct usage of "were" or "was"?

Tags: american-english, british-english, subjunctive-mood

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“If I was” or “If I were”. Which is more common, and which is correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/660/if-i-was-or-if-i-were-which-is-more-common-and-which-is-correct)

I am unsure whether to use "were" or "was" in the following instances

```
Instance 1:
```

> If I **were** you

or

> If I **was** you

```
Instance 2:
```

> If I **were** her

or

> If I **was** her

```
Instance 3:
```

> If I **were** a monkey

or

> If I **was** a monkey

Does it differ between forms of English (British, American)?

Comment: I have more to it than that, I'm asking for different subjects and regional differences.

Comment: ... all of which are mentioned among the answers to the question that I linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Were"** is often used instead of **"was"** after **"if"** and **"I wish"**.

You can use *"was"* instead of *"were"* in the following sentences:

> If I ***were*** you, I would stop smoking now.
>
> If he ***were*** in my place, he would have realized what I am going through.
>
> I wish I ***were*** on a holiday.

So, all your sentences are **correct**. And both these formats are acceptable in American as well as British English.