# "Be them" or "be they"?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, subjunctive-mood, grammatical-case, subject-verb-inversion

Which of the following is grammatical?

> - He had lollies be they red or blue?
> - He had lollies be them red or blue?

It seems as if it could be *them* as an object of *be*.

Comment: This seems such an unlikely thing for anyone to say that I don't think any answer given here would mean very much.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm interested in which is grammatically correct.

Comment: This sentence would not be interpreted as a question, but rather a literary statement that approximated "He had all lollies regardless of whether they were red or blue."

Comment: Neither of your examples is grammatical, because there's a mismatch between the syntax and the punctuation.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean "He had lollies. Were they red or blue?" (or "He has lollies. Are they red or blue?")

Comment: Unfortunately, this has been closed.  So I'll have to answer here.  "They" is the subject of "be" here, so "He had lollies, be they red or blue" is perfectly grammatical, albeit a rather unusual thing to say.  I cannot think of a context in which "He had lollies, be them red or blue" would be grammatical.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Neither of your two questions makes sense as written, and I do not know what the intent is.  For one thing, I don’t understand why they are questions; they do not look like such to me.

For another, the formulaic “be they *X* or *Y* ”, using present subjunctive and inversion as it does, is of a somewhat elevated register which may not be appropriate for all circumstances.  It has a slightly musty aroma of *littérature* to it, as of a sweetness possibly gone slightly off.  The use of the somewhat colloquial *lollies*  seems to fight against that register.  It is an odd mix.

Here are some alternate wording you may wish to consider, depending on your actual intent.

- He had red and blue lollies.
- He had lollies, both red ones and blue ones.
- He had lollies that were swirls of red and blue.
- He had lollies of swirling red and blue.
- Did he have either red or blue lollies?
- Did he have any red or blue lollies?
- Did he have any lollies, either red or blue?
- Did he have any lollies, whether red or blue?
- Whether red or blue, he had plenty of lollies.
- Both red and blue lollies he had laid in store.
- Whether blue or red or any other flavor, he had lollipops galore.
- Lollipops of every sort had he aplenty, be they  cherry or berry, or orange or lemon, or chocolate or peppermint.  Why, even the fabled Everlasting Gobsmacker was available — for weekly rental, that is, albeit at a rate well within reach of a child’s *monthly* allowance. As so often happens with such treasures, it was the late fees that were the Smackers’ sticking point, for what child born could ever part with one of Mr Wonka’s Everlasting Gobsmackers once it had danced upon his tongue its song of *A Thousand Flavours and a Flavour?*  Not one, I tell you, and so the Candyman’s siren song lured ever and anon a new generation to his musical cart: even the most loving of parents refused to pass their own Smackers on to their children, nor let lapse the lease.

[image]

---

### Disjunctive Concession, Inversion, and the Subjunctive

As for the use of the present subjunctive in *be they red or blue*, that is called ***disjunctive concession***, and it is in Contemporary English considered a literary style seldom heard elsewhere.  In his monumental work, *An Historical Syntax of the English Language*, Visser has this to say about it:

> The modally marked form is used in Old, Middle, and Modern English in
>   clauses of disjunctive concession or alternative hypothesis. In Present Day
>   English mainly literary.

I strongly advise you not to attempt to affect a literary register, let alone one that risks being perceived as archaic or poetic when that is not the intent, because I do not believe you yet have sufficient command of English to credibly pull it off.

Here, however, are some examples of authors who did do so.  You might compare your writing with theirs and decide whether you write like them.  Or should.

**1605 Shakespeare, *King Lear***

> **Be thy mouth or black or white**,
>   Tooth that poisons if it bite;

**c1795 Robert Burns, *Extemporary to Mr Syme***

> No more of your guests, **be they titled or not.**

**1954 J.R.R. Tolkien, *The Lord of the Rings***

> ‘As for me,’ said Imrahil, ‘the Lord Aragorn I hold to be my liege-lord, **whether he claim it or no**.’

**a1974 *ibid*, *The Silmarillion***:

> For Turgon took great liking for the sons of Galdor, and spoke much with them; and he wished indeed to keep them in Gondolin out of love, and not only for his law that no stranger, **be he Elf or Man**, who found the way to the secret kingdom and looked upon the city should ever depart again, until the King should open the leaguer, and the hidden people should come forth.

**1981 Gene Wolfe, *The Claw of the Conciliator***

> “Welcome visitors and fellow villagers! In the time it takes to draw breath 
>   thrice, you will see us smash this barrier and drag out the bandit Barnoch.  **Whether he be dead, or,** as we have good reason to believe — for he hasn’t been in  there that long — alive.

**1998 George Martin, *A Clash of Kings***

> “When we still kept the Old Way, lived by the axe instead of the pick, taking what we would, **be it wealth, women, or glory.**”

So yes, the form undeniably exists, although used differently than you attempted.  But no, I don’t think it works in what you are trying to write, especially where you attempted to use it.

Finally, you will notice how even in my own examples, I held off from using that form until the final, somewhat florid example.   Are you writing like that?

Comment: Do you reckon it doesn't sound good because there's inversion at the end of the sentence and not at the start? I noticed that your last sentence had two inversions. Could 'he had lollies, red and blue' make sense or could that be technically ambiguous because the 'he' might be interpreted as red and blue? What word for lollies is not colloquial? Thanks.

Comment: @Free Answer updated above.  But specifically: my last example sentence has at most one inversion not two; *lollipop* would be less colloquial than *lollies*; the postfix *red and blue* to lollies is an unusual ordering, and should like an exotic spice be used sparingly if at all; and no, *he* could certainly never be interpreted as a color!

Comment: OP should get extra Rep for providing you an excuse to compose this. Not to niggle (or Niggle), but there's no subjunctive *be* in the LotR quote.

Comment: @StoneyB Well true, but it is clearly disjunctive concession with characteristic subjunctive. I wanted to show that these coupled phenomena can, did, and even do occur with verbs other than *be*.  Those are *danged* tough to grep for, by the way.

Comment: @tchrist  Alas for the good old days when true scholars simply memorized all existing literature.

Comment: I like lot of what you have discussed. Let me clarify my original post:

Comment: I put a question mark at the end of each of the sentences as if to ask which one was correct. I thought of them on the spot; I was more interested in which construction of 'be they' or 'be them' is grammatically correct. 'Lollies' does not always mean 'lollipops', but means hard candy (including lollipops), soft sweets such as jubes, but not chocolate. So when I asked you what word that is not colloquial that could replace 'lollies', I was interested in what you would say. If you think 'candy' is a good choice, I would say that many people would say that sounds markedly American.

Comment: I believe that colloquial language can be used with a literary register, as in poetry. If I want to learn about a writing style, a great way would be to try writing in such a way. So of course I would not avoid using the phrase 'be they'. But thanks for looking out for me on that one! You might want to keep a check on that suggestion for other people. Say someone is learning Latin syntax, you wouldn't tell them to avoid experimenting with Latin word ordering because it is archaic, would you?

Comment: Are 'had he aplenty' and 'be they' two inversions?  Marthaª wrote that the OP sentence is ungrammatical. Is or isn't?

Comment: @Free Yes, Marthaª is right: your sentences are both wrong, with second being not merely nonsensical but ungrammatical. Notice how this makes no sense: “He had lollies, whether blue or red.”❡Sure, I suppose “had he” is ‘inversion’, but that was done for euphonious reasons. “Be they” is simply the normal V-S ordering that so often occurs in this sort of subjunctive; cf. *come the day, suffice it to say*.❡Starting with lollipops is not inversion though; it is just putting the most important word first, just like “Both red and blue he had”. “Child born” is inversion, just like a “man grown”. So?

Comment: Are you sure it is ungrammatical? What if the intended meaning of the sentence was that he had lollies whether they were red or blue? Whichever of the two colours, he *had* lollies in them. I was asking about inversions because you said there was one in your sentence; did you think there was a different reason for my asking?

Answer (score 7):

The verb *be* does not take an object. It has a subject and a complement, not an object.

Consequently **be them* cannot be correct.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I was thinking the 'be' was changing the subject (the lollies) and so the pronoun would be objective.

Comment: *Be* doesn't change anything. That's why it doesn't take an object. At most, it describes the subject by indicating equivalence to the complement.

Comment: "Be them" is actually indisputably correct in a sentence like "I knew someone would betray us; I didn't expect it to be them."