# "On or off campus" vs. "On- or off-campus" vs. "On-campus or off-campus"

Tags: word-choice, hyphenation, modifiers

> It does not matter if a student lives **__** as ...

I'm writing a formal report. Which of the following should I use to fill in the blank? Which one is correct and more formal and looks/sounds better?

a. "*on- or off-campus*"

b. "*on or off campus*"

c. "*on-campus or off-campus*"

Additional question: Is a. even grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2):

What Noah said is correct, here is why:

A hyphen is used to join two or more words to form a single adjective ***before a noun:***
On-campus library

If the compound modifiers come after a noun, they are not hyphenated:
The library is on campus

The Purdue Online Writing Lab was my source for this explanation: http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/576/01/

Comment: Downvoter, please provide feedback.  Do you believe my answer is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

No need for hyphens or anything of the like.

> It doesn't matter if a student *lives* on or off campus...

Or

> It doesn't matter if a student *lives* on campus or off campus...

On a side note, it should be *lives* not *live*.

Comment: True, we can’t all be writing [King Lear](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/90347/2085).