# “If I was to” vs. “If I were to”

Tags: british-english, conditionals, subjunctive-mood, simple-past, north-american-english

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [“If I was” or “If I were”. Which is more common, and which is correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/660/if-i-was-or-if-i-were-which-is-more-common-and-which-is-correct)

> 1. **If I *was* to** sum up my computer knowledge in one word, it would be *“destitute”*.
> 2. **If I *were* to** sum up my computer knowledge in one word, it would be *“destitute”*.

Which is correct?

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate. I just had doubts while writing [this](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68320/to-travel-30-km-from-india-to-sri-lanka-do-i-really-have-to-take-a-1500-km-20) about this exact thing. I found the other question, but it didn't answer my exact question. This one did. It's about the hypothetical "If I were to..." Therefore, I don't think this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

In British English, both of those are acceptable, and as I understand it, equivalent.  In American English, however,  *were* is required in hypothetical sentences like these, rather than  *was*. For detailed answers to your question, please see [“If I was” or “If I were”. Which is more common, and which is correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/660).  (But only one answer there, not high rated, mentions BE vs AE.)