# What tense is "If I were a bird, I could fly"

Tags: grammar, future, subjunctive-mood, present-tense, tenses

The sentence is not referring to any time past, present of future. It's just referring to an imaginary condition which has never existed and seemingly will never exist. Still, the sentence and other sentences of this type are said and spoken. So what can we say about their nature? Which tense are they, what type are they? Their clauses, etc.

Comment: You correctly tagged this with subjunctive mood. Your question may be related to http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/660/if-i-was-or-if-i-were-which-is-more-common-and-which-is-correct.

Comment: Thanks for all of yours responses. One thing has been clear that this sentence is in a state which is almost obsolete.
Now again I would like to know that how will we pronounce the same sentence in modern day English? I mean how will we convey the same meaning in present day English?

Comment: It isn't obsolete at all. It is present-day English, but some native speakers will say _If I was a bird, I'd be able to  fly_.

Comment: I agree with @BarrieEngland; while subjunctive mood is falling out of favor, I can hear it saying in a Monty Python voice, "I'm not dead yet." In versions earlier than MS Word 2007, the software would give you a squiggly green line on the verb (i.e., grammar correction) for "If I were" and suggest "If I was." Perversely, in MS Word 2010, it lets the subjunctive pass without a peep.

Comment: Thanks Barrie and Rajah.. but then if it is not obsolete. their must be a definite tense :( representing it. its main clause is, "If I were a bird" does not that suggest that it belongs to past indefinite?

Comment: The "were" construction does not necessarily indicate an impossible or ficticious condition. "If you were to phone me I would drop everything to talk with you."

Answer (score 21):

*Were* is the plural past tense form of *be*, used here in a counterfactual conditional idiom construction that is given various names, including "subjunctive", which often apply to other European languages, though not to English.

In fact, however, *tense* is not what you need to know here. [*Tense*](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/tense.html) only has to do with time -- past (*was/were*) and present (*am/is/are*) are the only tenses in English -- and the important thing about this construction is not **when** it occurs, but **whether** it occurs at all. And it doesn't; nothing happens. That's [what *counterfactual* means](https://glossary.sil.org/term/counterfactual-conditional-relation).

So, in essence, there is no real time reference involved. Especially since the second clause uses the [modal auxiliary](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html) *could*. Modals are defective verbs and are not inflected; therefore they can be said either to be always in the present tense, or to have no tense at all, depending on whether you require the first verb in an auxiliary chain to have a (perhaps inaudible) tense marker; take your pick.

It's true that there are certain uses of modals that retain some of their original preterite morphology, e.g, present *can* and preterite *could* in

- *When I was 25, I could do 100 pullups; now I can only do 99.*

But there's no "past" at all in

- *I could do that right now.*
- *Would you like to dance?*
- *You must come visit me soon.*

which are formed from historically preterite modals (*could, might, would, should, must*) instead of historically present ones (*can, may, will, shall*).

They're all idiomatic now. It's a mistake to expect any consistent semantic or grammatical regularity from modals, especially if there are [negatives](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) lurking about.

Comment: very helpful answer. What 'historically present modal', if there is one, is 'must' the preterite of? Pity you did not say anything about it...

Comment: English lost it a long time ago. It would be _muss_, or something like that, if it still existed. In German, which still has inflectable modal verbs, the present tense of "I must" is _Ich muss_ and the past tense (which means "I had to") is _Ich musste_. The final suffix is the normal -t/-d past that occurs in _could, should, would,_ and _might_.

Answer (score 6):

*If I were* is in the past subjunctive.  It is used for hypotheses.

*Then I could*, like *then I would be able to*, is construed to be in the conditional.  However, morphologically, *could* is the past tense of the modal *can*.

Comment: Or, if you, prefer, as I and Messrs Huddleston and Pullum do, it is irrealis _were_.

Comment: @BarrieEngland I’ve never understood this desire to reanalyse and rebrand such things all the way back to OE (and probably beyond) using different terms than have traditionally been applied to them. There is probably an argument to be made there, but if so, I doubt whether it would fit within these comments.

Answer (score 4):

The verbs in this sentence are vestiges of a subjunctive used in English to indicate conditions contrary to fact. We indicate this usage by using the plural form, where it exists, of the past tense.

*Were* is the plural past tense of *to be*.
*Could* is the past tense of *can* (no singular/plural distinction exists).

Example:
I *have gone* to the store to buy milk.
If I *had gone* to the store to buy milk...

Comment: _Plural past tense_ is an unsatisfactory description of _were_. _You were_ can be singular.

Comment: Understood. Looking for an easy guide for someone trying to figure out how to make the construction. Really, it's any non-first person formation, but to say, "Use the past plural" yields the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

We have to distinguish between the name of a tense, eg conditional, and its use.

Present tense can be used to refer to the future time.

"Conditional" as name means this tense/mood mostly occurs in if-clauses. But that does not cover all uses. - I tried but the window would not open, it was jammed. - Here we have a would-form that does not describe an unreal condition.

"Were" in "If I were a bird" is grammatically past subjunctive, but it does not refer to a past event. It expresses an unreal/hypothetical condition referring to present or future time.

So the name of a tense and its use can be very different.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are tenses on subjunctive moods.
The tense of "If I were a bird, I would fly to you" is present.
If I write this again in indicative mood: 
I AM NOT a bird and I CANNOT fly to you.

You also can use past subjunctive mood.
"If I had been a bird, I would have flown to you." = (indicative mood) I WAS not a bird and I COULD NOT fly to you.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is past. In “If I were a bird", the 'were' is the past subjunctive of 'to be'. If it were the present, the sentence would be, “If I be a bird", which is probably even more obsolete than the past form.

The Oxford English Dictionary lists 'were' as the past subjunctive in the 1st, 2nd and 3rd singular and plural. It lists 'be' as the present subjunctive in the 1st, 2nd and 3rd singular and plural. Despite the meaning, it isn't because of the 'were' itself that makes it somewhat irrealis; it is the use of the subjunctive itself, which has two forms