# User was or user were to store data?

Tags: subjunctive-mood

If the user was to store data....

(or)

If the user were to store data....

we normally use 
If I were, If they were but this usage confuses me. I've tried searching in search engines but haven't found any answer!

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/660/if-i-was-or-if-i-were-which-is-more-common-and-which-is-correct

Comment: I am aware of that usage as I had mentioned. My question is with 'user'-a common noun not the pronoun 'I'!

Comment: The earlier thread failed to point out that the writer may also use an inversion to express a conditional in this case.

Comment: It's not about a noun or a pronoun. It's about using a [subjunctive mood](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/subjunctive-verbs).

Comment: From the resource you had provided,I might have been able to generalize that 'were' must be used with singular subjects but wouldn't have been sure with it's usage with 'user' until someone like bobro had affirmed it.

Comment: @Mass Kent The answer depends also on whether you are concerned about present time (not tense) or past time situations.

Comment: @Marius Hancu That's a valid point! TY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Were" is correct, as the verb "to be" is here in the subjunctive mood. If this sounds clumsy to you, you could use inversion to express a conditional:

Should the user store data...

Comment: Got the answer.TY