# If I was or If I were - what to use

Tags: word-usage

I am a student who is studying software engineering and I have a big dream to become a world class developer in upcoming few years. I am planning to start a blog related to software engineering and I am thinking about the name: ifiwasasoftwareengineer.com

Do you think this is a appropriate use of English in this situation or should I better use 'ifiwere...'?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["If I was" or "If I were". Which is more common, and which is correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/660/if-i-was-or-if-i-were-which-is-more-common-and-which-is-correct)

Answer (score 1):

'If I was' suggests you don't think you ever will be a software engineer. Grasp the nettle and choose 'wheniamasoftwareengineer.com'. otherwise your dreams will stay as dreams. Good luck in your career!

Answer (score 0):

<del>"If I were" is generally used for things you'll most likely never actually *be*, like in "if I were you" or "if I were in her shoes". "If I was" doesn't carry such a connatation. In your case, I would go with "was".</del>

EDIT:

Using "were" here makes the clause have a [subjunctive mood](http://grammarist.com/grammar/subjunctive-mood/), which actually means nothing for the future likelihood of the clause, as Chappo mentioned below. Subjunctive mood *can* give a meaning of wishfulness or possibility, and is used to [express various states of unreality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood), which is different than what I first suggested. "Was", on the other hand, is in indicative mood, which deals with facts and doesn't carry the same possibility of subtext.

In any case, I agree with Jonathan above - don't make it wishful thinking!

Comment: Regarding your answer, "were" is the subjunctive mood of "was", and neither has anything to do with the *likelihood* of the condition occurring. In any case, your basic premise that the subjunctive indicates an unachievable condition is wrong - consider "If I were sick with a cold, I would still go to work" or "If I were a retiree, I would have more leisure time".