# Is "forsought" right in this case?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, literary-english

I was trying to write a poem in an old fashioned way and I wished to use the verb *forseek* in a verse, but when I searched about this verb I found that it isn't widely used not even in old texts (if it is at all) since I found only a few dictionary entries for it.

So, I want to know if the following verse makes sense or if I really must replace *forseek* for a more usual verb:

> "They forsought something that were their own, something that (...)"

I'm not an English speaker.

Comment: *"forsought"* is the simple past and past tense of *"forseek"*

Comment: http://www.yourdictionary.com/forseek

Comment: Note that "forseek" is archaic.

Comment: Check your agreement in “Something that were”

Comment: When you are writing a poem it's well within your artistic license to use old-fashioned words if you want to. You can even invent some, that's the beauty of creating art.

Comment: I politely disagree as far the use of an old-fashioned word is concerned. No word is old-fashioned in my opinion. Go ahead and use forseek/ foresight etc. foresight
1
n seeing ahead; knowing in advance; foreseeing
Synonyms:
farsightedness, prevision, prospicience---vide https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/foresight----we have hindsight probably  being a word to understand the nature of an event after it has happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided *foreseek* is a valid verb (which it [appears to be](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forseek)), it will then be conjugated just like any other verb. The correct point of comparison would be *seek*. You are speaking in the past tense, therefore *sought*. *Foreseek* becomes *foresought*.

You needn't worry about not being able to find dictionary entries for conjugated versions of a verb. If you can find the infinitive you are good to go.

As a comment points out, check your number agreement. Something is singular. Therefore:

> They sought something that was their own.

You could also avoid the number question altogether with

> They sought something of their own.

Comment: Nope, the commenter was mistaken.  *They forsought something that **were** their own* is a correct use of hypothetical *were* for that period when used to express doubt about that thing’s existence. See [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/339053/2085) for the historical nuances.