# Was vs. Were in the Subjunctive Mood

Tags: subjunctive-mood, mood

I am having trouble identifying the difference between the use of was and were. For example:
Sarah wishes she was/were more like mother. 
Would it be were? If it is were, why?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/660/when-to-use-if-i-was-vs-if-i-were/662