# Use of plural form of auxiliary verb for singular subject

Tags: word-choice, tenses, auxiliary-verbs

This is an excerpt from an article published on the Nautilus website:

> ...We in the 21st century would be shocked **if an educated adult were** unable to identify the continents on a world map, yet we are quite comfortable with widespread obliviousness about anything but the most superficial highlights...

Why has 'were' been used instead of singular 'was'?

Comment: The plural verb form, or what *looks* like a plural verb, is used in several constructions, including conditional statements that talk about hypothetical or contrary-to-fact situations. This question really belongs on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use "If I was" vs. "If I were"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/660/when-to-use-if-i-was-vs-if-i-were)

Comment: This "were" is called the 'irrealis' mood, a special mood form unique to "be", and limited to 1st and 3rd person singular. Many people would use preterite "was" instead. Irrealis "were" is more formal than "was" and is preferred by older speakers.