# Is "was" in the subjunctive mood here, needing to be changed to "were"?

Tags: subjunctive-mood

My question pertains to the following:

> Mother knocked on the door because she said the bell might wake up the baby if he **was** asleep.

Should *was* be changed to *were* here? Thanks!

Comment: First of all, the subjunctive mood can be either [*were* or *was*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/660/when-to-use-if-i-was-vs-if-i-were). However, this sounds much more like the regular backshifting of reported speech involving a conditional to me. (*She said, "If you knock on the door, you might wake up the baby if he **is** asleep."*)

Comment: No: "was" is fine. It's simply a past tense form. Please understand that English does not have a subjunctive mood. The "were" is called 'irrealis' mood, not subjunctive.

Comment: @JasonBassford Would this mean that you'd go with _was_ here? Thanks!

Comment: @BillJ It seems to me that English does have the subjunctive mood; it's just rare. See, for example, https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subjunctive_mood.

Comment: @TheEditor Since I don't believe it's in the subjunctive, then, yes. I would use *was*. If I thought it were ;) in the subjunctive, I would personally use *were*.

Comment: @TheEditor Incidentally, saying that "the subjunctive mood doesn't exist because it's not called that, it's called *irrealis*," is just sidestepping the question. That kind of criticism of naming isn't helpful when it's obvious what's being referred to anyway. In short, you say potato and I say potato. (Which makes much more sense when you actually hear it …) So, whether you want to think of it as subjunctive or irrealis, the point is I don't think that's the mood in the specific example sentence. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!