# What's the difference between these two sentences

Tags: meaning, conditionals

I came across the following sentence:

> If she were to leave earlier she would make it to the train.

Does that mean the same as

> If she leaves earlier she will make it to the train.

I do not understand the usage of the *if she were to leave earlier*.

Comment: Lookup "English subjunctive"

Comment: For all _practical_ purposes, it means the same. Using the subjunctive makes it a hypothesis rather than a prediction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use "If I was" vs. "If I were"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/660/when-to-use-if-i-was-vs-if-i-were)

Answer (score 0):

The verbal form "were" is a subjunctive in the present grammatical context; essential explantions can be found in the pdf "englishsubjunctive.pdf".

> ii. Hypothetical subjunctive
> This usage of the subjunctive is called for whenever the situation described by the verb is ‘hypothetical,’ whether
> wished for, feared, or suggested; the common thread is that the situation is not the current state of affairs. This
> subjunctive can occur with or without a word like "if" or "whether" that specifically marks a phrase as hypothetical. When
> if is omitted, an inverted syntax is usually used:
>
> - Were I the President...
> - If I were the king of the world...
> - Be he alive or be he dead...
> - If I were the President...
>
> In most varieties of English, this subjunctive can be replaced by an indicative when the if-form is used:
>
> - If I was the President ...
> - If he was a ghost...
>
> Another use of the hypothetical subjunctive occurs with the verb wish – I wish I were a bird; Joseph wishes he were a
> cowboy. This too is often replaced with the unmarked form. I wish I was a bird expresses exactly the same meaning, but
> technically "was" is not a subjunctive form.
> Some use the marked form even in the absence of a hypothetical situation – Johnny asked me if I were afraid –
> simply as a conditioned variant that follows "if" and similar words. This is commonly considered a hypercorrection.

What is to be particularly heeded  in this explanation is  the sentence "*the common thread is that the situation is not the current state of affairs.*". This means that is understated in the sentence "if she were to … train." that she is not actually going to leave earlier.
The form using the indicative, equivalent as far as it carries the idea of a hypothetical situation, is somewhat different inasmuch as it does not understate that her leaving was not planned to be earlier; her actual plan might  be after all be to leave earlier.

Comment: This is why this construction is often called _Irrealis_, which is just the Latin word for 'unreal'. That's to distinguish it from the _Hypothetical_, like the _arrive_ in _They asked that she arrive ten minutes early tomorrow_. Both of these constructions are often called "subjunctive" because they have senses similar to those of languages with real subjunctive moods, like Latin or Spanish. But one uses the past tense and the other uses the infinitive, both in situations where they're unusual. This is supposed to call attention to the construction, and sometimes it does.